# Undefined when selecting rel value using class

Tags: jquery, class, rel

I am using [UIKit](http://getuikit.com/) template. I have 2 buttons to toggle between. When I click on one button it will get a class `uk-active`. But when I try to get the `rel` attribute value using jQuery on form submit, it says undefined. My code is below

```
<button class="uk-button uk-width-1-2 uk-active" rel="0" type="button"><span class="fbaicon"></span> RENT</button>
<button class="uk-button uk-width-1-2" rel="1" type="button"><span class="fbaicon"></span> BUY</button>
```

And my jQuery is,

```
var type = $('.uk-active').attr('rel');
alert(type);
```

I am sure that class uk-active always exists for one of these two buttons

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/tat5o3c3/

Comment: can you try `alert($('.uk-active').length);` - move your script to dom ready handle if it is not already

Comment: It is already in DOM ready

Comment: @ArunPJohny : When try `.length` I get the length. But not getting the required rel value

Comment: @Corner Can you reproduce this on `jsfiddle`?

Comment: @Tushar : Yes. It will work if you try like that. But my situation is different. When I click on 'BUY' button it will assign `uk-active` class to that button. And if I click on 'RENT' rent will get `uk-active` class. That means classes are being changed. And I need to get the value of the button when I submit the form

Answer (score 1):

check whether code is executing before the DOM is loaded.
Keep scripts in `$(document).ready();`

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following code. It is working successfully for me.

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var type = $('.uk-active').attr('rel');
    alert("outside document ready "+type);
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var type = $('.uk-active').attr('rel');
    alert("inside document ready "+type);

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button class="uk-button uk-width-1-2 uk-active" rel="0" type="button"><span class="fbaicon"></span> RENT</button>
    <button class="uk-button uk-width-1-2" rel="1" type="button"><span class="fbaicon"></span> BUY</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You however did not load UIKit

Comment: if you load also same answer will appear.

Comment: No. the scripts wrapped inside document.ready will execute only when the DOM is ready.